# Configuration System Failed To Initialize (Not XML issue)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, excel, add-in

I have looked at [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6367203/configuration-system-failed-to-initialize) [other](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1327083/configuration-system-failed-to-initialize-error-while-loading-a-custom-section-f) [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6436157/configuration-system-failed-to-initialize?lq=1) here on how to solve this and all point to malformed XML in the app.config file. However, my app.config seems to have the `<configSections>` node in the correct place (first child node of `<configuration>`):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <configSections>
        <sectionGroup name="userSettings"
                      type="System.Configuration.UserSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" >
            <section name="My_Excel_Addin_Name.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" allowExeDefinition="MachineToLocalUser" requirePermission="false" />
        </sectionGroup>
    </configSections>
    <userSettings>
        <My_Excel_Addin_Name.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="Host" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
            <setting name="Port" serializeAs="String">
                <value />
            </setting>
        </My_Excel_Addin_Name.Properties.Settings>
    </userSettings>
</configuration>
```

Is it possible that it is something to do with the name of my project containing spaces ("My Excel Addin Name")?

I also thought it may have been something to do with refactoring namespace names in VS2010 so I rebuilt my project (Excel Add In) in a new project where no refactoring was done but the issue still remains.

I have left out some user settings above but have gone through them to check for duplicates and none exist.

This only happens when I deploy the add in with a windows installer. When I build in release and run on my machine without using the installer, the issue doesn't occur.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Any ideas what could be the issue here?

Comment: I've heard of blaming the installer for a number of things but never a malformed XML document. :)

Comment: @ChristopherPainter: read the title...

Comment: The title where you assert it's not an XML issue but then you post malformed XML?  Yah....  good luck.

Comment: Typo dude: keep your knickers on :)

Answer (score 1):

Go into Visual Studio and select File | New | Item and select General | XML file.  Paste the contents of your XML into this new file.

Visual Studio Intellisense will immediately inform you that your XML is malformed.   Your setting[@name='Port'] element is missing it's close tag.

Comment: That was a copy / paste typo, the `</setting>` tag for port is in the original XML.

Comment: The answer is valid based on what you posted.  Attention to details is very important in this industry.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by deleting the following folder:

```
C:\Users\user.name\AppData\Local\Microsoft_Corporation\ExcelAddIn.vsto_Path_somehorrible32charhash
```

Comment: You said "when you deploy using windows installer".  I hope you know to test alpha installers on snapshotted virtual machines so you can just revert the state and not have to track down weird problems like this.  I also hope you know not to test installers on your own development box.